# AbortController does not cancel axios.get

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, axios

I'm trying to cancel an API call using AbortController. For the call, I'm using axios. To test how to cancel a call, I'm trying it with this call before implementing it into my project :

```js
const c = new AbortController();
const r = axios.get("https://www.google.com:81",{signal: c.signal});
c.abort();
```

But when I test this code example, my request is not aborted (it just timeout, which is normal, but it should be aborted before timing out as I'm not awaiting).
Do someone see where is my mistake ? Maybe I haven't completly understood the way to use AbortController, but this code example sounds good to me.

Comment: What makes you think it isn't cancelled? In what environment? What version of Axios? (Since Axios used to use only its own form of cancellation, but now [supports both](https://axios-http.com/docs/cancellation).) It works for me using a Chromium browser: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dyDyO.png

Comment: I'm using a Chromium browser too (google chrome). When I look into the DevTools in network, I see my request being timeout after some time, and I don't see anywhere "cancelled" or "aborted"

Comment: I'm using axios version 1.3.3, I didn't know that the version could be a problem

Comment: Don't know what to tell you. There will be an element of timing to this, but with the code in the question, it seems reliable: https://jsfiddle.net/tjcrowder/yc6amLh2/ Tried Vivaldi, Chrome, Chromium, Brave, and also Firefox (non-Chromium, of course :-) ).

Comment: The page linked above says they started supporting `AbortController` in v0.22.0, so that version should be fine.

Comment: I see that it's working in your example, I really don't understand why in my case I have (failed)net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

Comment: I use exactly your code example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I use fetch instead of axios, it works well. I really don't undersand why, but I guess I'll be using this instead

## Edit

The axios [CancelToken](https://axios-http.com/docs/cancellation) are working, so I'll use that even if it's deprecated (but both can be used)

Comment: Strangely enough, it AbortController doesn't work either for me with vue3